# Cannot run multiple instances in bluemix with a python flask application

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, multiple-instances

I have a python web application that uses a file system for processing data...   When I go into bluemix and click on the instances click and increase instances to 2.   I start to get crashes..   With just a simple test of opening two tabs in my browser, when i run the user request, one of the user instances crashes immediately every time.     the logs show these errors.

Thanks for the help, not sure if there is a way to assign a client to an instance?  Maybe it is bouncing back and forth among instances?

```
APP/0
[2017-04-20 04:22:25,806] ERROR in app: Exception on /convertdoc [POST]
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1725, in make_response
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
ValueError: View function did not return a response
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
return self.finalize_request(rv)
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
75.126.52.20 - - [20/Apr/2017 04:22:25] "POST /convertdoc HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
Apr 20, 2017 12:22:25 AM

APP/0
response = self.make_response(rv)
```

Comment: when it crashes i get back a 500 error:   Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: When I get the 500 error, I can just keep retrying like 4xs and then it seems to catch the response again and I can continue the user experience.   very strange behavior...   Am I missing some code or parameter that sets up the application to run on multiple bluemix instances?

Comment: @JohnVaughan does the app definitely work ok when there is only one instance?  If so, this question should be flagged to reopen.

Comment: @JohnVaughan can you add you view code?